# Simple addEventlistener not working I dont know how to fix it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So, I wasn't happy about how many browsers output errors in Javascript (in the console) therefore I went ahead, and programmed a simple console plugin for any website, which could execute any function with some extras like a loop function.  To submit your command for execution you only have to press enter. And here is, where the problem comes:

My "Plugin" stops any other event listener from working other than its own ones.  I don't know what I did wrong, but I have the concern, that it has to do with some of my event listeners!!!

Here's the code.

***Written in JavaScript!***

```js
                window.onload = function() {
    var isIE = /*@cc_on!@*/ false || !!document.documentMode;

    document.querySelector("body").innerHTML += "<div style='border:1px solid black; width: 400px; height:300px;overflow:auto;background-color:rgb(29, 29, 29); color:rgb(10, 160, 160);' id='consoleoutput'></div><div id='speed'></div>";
    if ( /*@cc_on!@*/ false || !!document.documentMode || !isIE && !!window.StyleMedia) {
        document.querySelector("body").innerHTML += "<input style='border:1px solid black; width: 357px;background-color:rgb(40, 40, 40); color:rgb(300, 300, 300);' type='text' placeholder='type your commands/functions here' id='consoleinput'></input><span>loop</span><input type='checkbox' id='loopini'>";
    } else {
        document.querySelector("body").innerHTML += "<form action='#' id='thefasdasd'><input style='border:1px solid black; width: 357px;background-color:rgb(40, 40, 40); color:rgb(300, 300, 300);' type='text' placeholder='type your commands/functions here' id='consoleinput'></input><span>loop</span><input type='checkbox' id='loopini'></form>";
    }
    if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Firefox") != -1) {
        window.location.href = "#";

    } else {
        window.location.href = "?#";
    }

    if (isIE) { document.write("Internet Explorer is not supported please use any other browser") }
    document.querySelector("#consoleinput").addEventListener('keypress', function(e) {
        var key = e.which || e.keyCode;
        if (key === 13) {
            if ($('input[id=loopini]').prop('checked')) {
                var inh = document.getElementById("consoleinput").value;
                loop(inh);
            } else {
                var inh = document.getElementById("consoleinput").value;
                executeScript(inh);
            }
        }
    })
};
if (document.getElementById("speed").innerHTML == "") {
    document.getElementById("speed").innerHTML = 600;
}

function changeloopspeed(speed) {  document.getElementById("speed").innerHTML = speed; }

function loop(b) {
    sayb("Gib 'changeloopspeed(die neue Geschwindigkeit in ms)' ein um die Geschwindigkeit des loops zu ändern!")
    var a = document.getElementById("speed").innerHTML;
    var timedconsolefunc = function() {
        var asdas = $('input[id=loopini]').prop('checked');

        executeScript(b);

        if (asdas) {
            setTimeout(timedconsolefunc, a);
        }
    }
    setTimeout(timedconsolefunc, a);
}

function say(a) {
    if (a != undefined) {
        document.getElementById("consoleoutput").innerHTML += "<p style='color:rgb(48, 243, 96)'>" + a + "</p>";
        scrollTo();
    }
}

function saya(a) {
    document.getElementById("consoleoutput").innerHTML += "<p style='color:rgb(10, 160, 160)'>" + a + "</p>";
    scrollTo();
}

function sayb(a, b) {
    document.getElementById("consoleoutput").innerHTML += "<p style='color:rgb(100, 160, 160)'> " + a + " <span style='color:rgb(48, 243, 96)'> " + b + "</span></p>";
    scrollTo();
}

function saye(a) {
    document.getElementById("consoleoutput").innerHTML += "Error: <p style='color:rgb(999, 0, 0)'>" + a + "</p>";
    scrollTo();
}

function executeScript(source) {
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.onload = script.onerror = function() { this.remove(); };
    script.src = "data:text/plain;base64," + btoa("function asdfasd() {try{" + source + "}catch(error) {saye(error.message)}}; var exer = asdfasd(); if (exer != undefined){sayb('Returned value:',exer)} else {saya('no \\'return \\' was found')}");
    document.body.appendChild(script);
    document.getElementById("consoleoutput").innerHTML += "code Executed!<br/>"
    document.getElementById("consoleinput").value = "";
}
var scrollTo = function(elem) {
    var elem = document.getElementById("consoleoutput");
    elem.scrollTop = elem.scrollHeight;

    console.log("test");
    return this;
};
```

Does it have to do with the:

> window.onload = function() }

???!!!  Please help.

When I try to make the code smaller for demonstration purpose then there is the problem always gone.  So all I know is, that in the code above is somewhere a problem, and I can't find it!!

Does anyone out there know how to solve this problem?!

I don't know, what I did wrong.

**Your Dennis**

Comment: Don't [repost closed questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59371969/i-have-a-problem-with-my-self-programmed-console-for-java-script) - instead, please fix the existing question

Comment: *my ""Plugin"" stops any other Eventlistener from working other than its own ones* What sort of event listeners attached outside of this snippet fail to work? Can you give an example? Or is some part of the above snippet intended to illustrate that?

Comment: I deleted the other one

Comment: ther is no example I mean every Eventlistener

Comment: as soon as I include the above code on any Website, any other event listener won't work again. 
if it matters: im using chrome

Comment: You unconditionally assign to the `window.location.href`, but that will replace the page. What's the purpose of those lines?

Comment: I even watched each Step in the Program with the Chrome setp by step code execution an in the instance of executing some addeventlis... It doesn't even show up under the active eventlisteners, and that without any other command being executed after:... I think I broke Javascript!!!

Comment: the window.... is for the <form action="#"></form>

Comment: it is supposed to stop the page from reloading when you press enter in the form

Answer (score 1):

The only way your code seems to break when it comes to event listeners seems to be when it overrides existing listeners in mediums like `window.onload = ...`, in which case, it should be `window.addEventListener("load", ...)`